# Poker Range String Format Using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to format some strings using a SQL function

For the guys that know what I'm talking about,

let's say I have a range of QQ+,ATs+

- This means QQ or better and ATs or better
- The new string should be this: AA,KK,QQ,ATs,AJs,AQs,AKs

Using my SQL function I can extract the first string, but what I'm looking for is the second one.
How can I achieve that?

This is the custom function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getautonote(
    input_id_player integer,
    input_pattern text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
   iOutput text;
BEGIN
   SELECT note 
   FROM notes_auto 
   WHERE id_player = input_id_player 
     AND note LIKE input_pattern 
   LIMIT 1 INTO iOutput;

   RETURN iOutput;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION getautonote(integer, text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: next time try to provide a 
  [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) with a schema and some data so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
   much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What mean the `+` in QQ+ and What is ATs ? I mean I know poker, and still not sure what those mean.

Comment: Ty for letting me know about SqlFiddle but this doesn't help with my problem. With my function I'm retrieving a column on the database, there's no point of adding anything more imo, what I'm really looking for is some code to format the output of the function. Regarding the +, I explained that, it means QQ or better = QQ,KK,AA . Same thing regarding ATs, this means ATs,AJs,AQs,AKs.

Comment: yes I update the format to make it clear. If you dont provide the fiddle at least say what is the imput? Is a string? is an array? Define what a range mean

Comment: T mean figure? J,Q,K ?

Comment: Sorry your question isnt clear enough. Is there a function is there a string. What you want. [**Need an Answer? Actually, No ... You Need a Question**](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx)

Comment: I have build a SQL function that allows me to retrieve a column in the database (don't ask me why, but this is the only way to get that column using a specific software).  
The function is working great but the output isn't what I want, in the first example I think it is pretty clear what I'm trying to do.  
In poker, range notation using the '+' to mean 'anything better than'.

this is an example of the query and the output  
http://i.imgur.com/tLEfDMN.png  

Clearly I need help with my function, because I want the formatted string to be returned

Comment: I try to provide some links to give you tips of how improve your question please read it. Here is how should be a proper question. I have a function  `F()` when I pass `F('QQ')` I have this `xxxx` but want this `yyyy` My function create that string doing `A, B, C`

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but I explained several times, providing a query example, the output example, and the function code. I don't really understand what other things do you need. What I need is a function that retrieves a string from the column and then reformat it. That's all

Comment: I dont want be rude neither, but I dont see query sample, I see the function (I put it on the question for you). You get a `input_pattern` but you dont explain what is a valid pattern.  What is valid input `QQ`,  `QQ+`, `QQ+,AT+`? Now back to the function. What is `notes_auto` and what is in `note` That is why I say show us some data and schema.

Comment: There is no way that function get `QQ+,AT+` and return `AA,KK,QQ,ATs,AJs,AQs,AKs` unless note has that string.

Comment: Is this about a card game? (I've heard people play them, but never understood the logic, nor the notation)

Comment: @wildplasser yes, is about `poker`  a card game. I guess you are even more lost than me :)

Comment: I think I have it. You want us create the whole function for scratch to return that value but you dont say how you want the string be created. Or what rules we should use. We arent here to do the job for you, at least show us some effort.

Comment: well, he has posted the function, but it is completely unclear what it is supposed to do.